# call a childs version of a function instead of a parents?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, overriding

Okay, so I got two classes.

```
class a{
public:
a(){};
void print(){cout << "hello"};
}

class b : public a{
public:
void print(){cout << "hello world";}
}
```

And a array of parents with a child

```
a blah[10];
blah[5] = b();
```

Than I call print, and want it to say hello world.

```
blah[5].print();
```

But it calls the parent. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be fixed by declaring the function virtual, a la:

```
class a{
public:
    virtual void print(){
        cout << "hello";
    }
}

class b : public a{
public:
    virtual void print() {
        cout << "hello world";
    }
}
```

This is how one implements polymorphism in C++. More here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function

However, it should be noted that in your example, it will never call the child function, because you are using object *values*, not pointers/references to objects. To remedy this,

```
a * blah[10];
blah[5] = new b();
```

Then:

```
blah[5]->print();
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is run-time polymorphism, which means to have the object take "many forms" (i.e. a or b), and act accordingly, as the program runs.  In C++, you do this by making the function `virtual` in the base class `a`:

```
virtual void print() {cout << "hello"};
```

Then, you need to store the elements by pointer or reference, and - as in general the derived classes can introduce new data members and need more storage - it's normal to create the objects on the heap with `new`:

```
a* blah[10];
blah[5] = new b();
```

Then you can call:

```
blah[5]->print();
```

And it will call the `b` implementation of `print()`.

You should later `delete blah[5]` (and any other's you've pointed at memory returned by `new`).

In practice, it's a good idea to use a container that can delete the objects it contains when it is itself destructed, whether due to leaving scope or being deleted.  `std::vector<>` is one such container.  You can also use smart-pointers to automate the deletion of the `a` and `b` objects.  This helps make the code correct if exceptions are thrown before your `delete` statements execute, and you want your program to keep running without leaking memory.  The boost library is the easiest/best place to get a smart pointer implementation from.  Together:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

std::vector<boost::shared_pointer<a> > blah(10);

blah[5] = new b();
```

(It's more normal to use vectors with `push_back()`, as it automatically grows the vector to fit in all the elements you've added, with the new total available by calling `vector::size()`.)

Answer (score 0):

It does that because you told the compiler that your instance was of type `a`. It's in an array of `a` objects, right? So it's of type `a`!

Of course, you want the method in `b` to overwrite the one in `a`, despite having a reference of the parent type. You can get that behaviour using the `virutal` keyword on function declaration in the parent class.

```
virtual void print(){cout << "hello"};
```

**Why does it work like that?**

Because when you cast your object to the parent class, you introduced an ambiguity. When this object's `print()` is called, how should we treat it? It is of type `b`, but the reference is of type `a`, so the sorrounding code may expect it to behave like `a`, not `b`!

To disambiguate, the `virtual` keyword is introduced. `virtual` functions are always overridden, if the object is of a child class containing a method with the same signature.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Declare `a::print()` as virtual and use **pointer/reference** to call the `print()` function. When you do `blah[5] = b()`, it does object slicing. You don't have any effect calling a virtual function using object.